# Can github have the botton that "do nothing and merge"?

Tags: git, github

I get a PR (Someone fork my repository and push a PR to me).

And I add that as a remote, fetch and merge locally:

```sh
$ git remote add <name> <url>
$ git fetch <name>
$ git cherry-pick <hash-list> # I resolve the conflict then
```

Then I push to my github repository:

```
$ git push
```

Now I hope that PR will tagged by `merged` but nothing happen... It is still `open`.

Can I make that PR just marked `merged` but do nothing? I do not want to just close it.

---

@matt said that I do those in a bad way. But the Github tell me that I need to:

```sh
$ git checkout -b <new-branch> <origin-branch>
$ git pull <URL> <branch>
$ git checkout <origin-branch>
$ git merge --no-ff <new-branch>
$ git push origin master
```

I cannot use those because that PR's commit graph is messly and I really need `cherry-pick` to make my repo's git history clear. I think what I do is that Github let me do... But I did it totally in a bad way...

Comment: "And I clone that and merged locally. Then I push to my github repository." Careful. Clone is a technical term. What did you really do? Show your actual commands to Git. What did you say to Git, and what did Git say to you?

Comment: @matt , thx, I fix it.

Comment: No you didn't. You are juggling technical terms in a nonsensical way. Don't describe what you did, because you clearly don't know how to describe it accurately. _Show_ what you did, as I asked you before.

Comment: And what does get a PR mean? Do you mean someone forked your repo and pushed a PR to your repo from the fork?

Comment: @matt , how about now? I add the shell command.

Comment: I am so sorry that I use the word `clone`. It is not right. I am so stupid :cry:

Comment: But after `git checkout <origin-branch>` you could clean up the commits, and then merge. So you _can_ do what GitHub says.

Comment: @matt , thx for your kindly help. I trid. I follow the document you give but nothing happen - the PR is still open. I find the last step is: `Create a new pull request with your new branch.`, which is not what I want to do. I just want to clean up those commit, push and mark the PR `merged`, but not another helpless branch and another new helpless branch. It really dismay me.

Comment: I've answered what you originally asked.

Comment: @matt , I know, but both looks not working...

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly legal to fetch a pull request branch, merge it locally, and push. The problem is that you didn't do that. You didn't fetch the pull request at all. And you didn't merge anything either. Instead, you manually reached into the requester's repo and cherry picked a commit into your own branch and pushed.

So as far as GitHub is concerned, nothing happened except that some unexplained new commits appeared magically on your branch. GitHub doesn't know where those commits came from and it doesn't care. It doesn't  mark the pull request as merged because it wasn't merged.

The pull request was never in the requester's repo. It was (and still is) in *your* repo. So you fetched the wrong thing. There was never a good reason to add the requester's repo as a remote and you should not have done it.

In answer to your question: yes, you can just close the PR on GitHub. In effect, that rejects the PR, which is not very nice and is not historically accurate. But it is certainly something you can do at this point.

Personally I think it would be better to merge the PR, as you intended to do all along. But it's up to you.

Comment: Sorry that (fetch a pull request branch, merge it locally, and push) **is** what I want to do. But I get not idea how to do it... I am so stupid that I think what I did is right...

Comment: GitHub tells you how to do it. https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally

Comment: I believe I have answered your question now.